# Text on several lines makes svg shrink

Tags: css, html, svg, flexbox

I'm trying to create rows with svg + text with flexbox, and I'm facing an issue.

When the text is too long and takes 2 lines, the svg is shrinking. The more there are lines, the more it shrinks

Note : the svg is a placeholder for the moment

Here is the code :

```
<div class="wrapper">

 <div class="container">
   <div class="svg"></div>
   <p>lorem</p>
 </div>

 <div class="container">
  <div class="svg"></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam. </p>
 </div>

</div>
```

And the css :

```
.wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 40px 12px;
 }

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
 }

.svg {
  margin-right: 20px;
  height: 20px; 
  width: 20px; 
  background-color: #DEDEDE;
 }

 p {
  margin: 0;
 }
```

Here is a codepen so you can see what I mean by "shrinking" : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YdWyBM?editors=1100

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your magic trick is `.svg {flex-shrink: 0;}`. That's how you disable shrinking for a flex child.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 40px 12px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.svg {
  margin-right: 20px;
  height: 20px; 
  width: 20px; 
  background-color: #DEDEDE;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="svg"></div>
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="svg"></div>
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="svg"></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="svg"></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris </p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to help! If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

i added `max-width:calc(100% - 40px)` to `p` for `margin-right:20px` and `width:20px`

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 40px 12px;
 }

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
 }

.svg {
  margin-right: 20px;
  height: 20px; 
  width: 20px; 
  background-color: #DEDEDE;
 }

 p {
  margin: 0;
  max-width:calc(100% - 40px);
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

 <div class="container">
   <div class="svg"></div>
   <p>lorem</p>
 </div>

 <div class="container">
  <div class="svg"></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam. </p>
 </div>

</div>
```